# Does Maven do undeploy before deploying (Jenkins)?

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

I am using Jenkins and Maven plugin to build and deploy my application, which works perfectly. I have noticed something, after changing the code of my classes I build and deploy my application using Jenkins I get the deployment successfully and the changes were applied -> my new application was deployed.

**My question is:** I thought that we have to undeploy an application if we want to deploy a new version of this application. Does Maven do the undeploy? how does it work?

---

My work consisted of these steps:

1. I have created a new job in Jenkins (Maven project - nameJob = MavenTest)
2. I have created a new Maven project using Netbeans
3. I built and deployed my project using netbeans (worked, showing a white page with Hello world! text <- the desired page (a fresh new Maven project))
4. I cleaned my project using Netbeans
5. I copied my project (3 folders: TestMavenJenkins-ear, TestMavenJenkins-ejb and TestMavenJenkins-web + pom.xml)
6. I pasted it to `JenkinsHome/workspace/MavenTest`
7. The build configuration consists of adding pom.xml to RootPOM (which is done by deafult by Jenkins)
8. I configured the Post-build Actions as shown in the image below

[image: Post-build Actions]

9. I run my job and all works
10. I change `Hello world!` to `Hellow world 2!`
11. I copied the project again to `JenkinsHome/workspace/MavenTest`
12. I run my job again and the deployment was done without error! It showed `Hellow World 2!`

The content of my `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>testsApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestMavenJenkins</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>TestMavenJenkins</name>
  <modules>
    <module>TestMavenJenkins-ear</module>
    <module>TestMavenJenkins-web</module>
    <module>TestMavenJenkins-ejb</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: How is your deployment implemented? What do you expect from an "undeployment"? Are you talking about servlet containers or something?

Comment: @StephenKing I'm not expecting anything from an "undeployment". I deployed an application (built with Ant), deploying it again generated an error: application deployed already! Using Maven for the same scenario didn't generate an error, I assumed that there were an undeployment. I want to know who is responsible of this undeployment, Jenkins or Maven or .. , if there is an undeployment at all!

Comment: Okay, so still, what is "deployment" for you? Maven doesn't just have magically access to your production servers, so you probably have configured something. In general, it is not even "defined", if maven or Jenkins do your deployment (copy files via SSH, do this and that etc). That's implementation specific. We don't know your implementation.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you post relevant pieces of your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @StephenKing I didn't really understand what do you mean, I will try to answer your question by editing my question and describe all what I have done step by step. I hope I can answer you so you can help me =)

Comment: Thanks for updating. So you're using some servlet container (Glassfish) it seems. That was not obvious ;-) Sorry, I'm out. I never deployed into a servlet container of any kind.